# Customize logs in inspec chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Ruby/chef/inspec newbie here.

We are using inspec chef for testing existence of the user in linux.

When running something like

```
describe user(username) do
      it "should exist" do
        # The existence check itself is included in the custom description.
        expect(subject.exists?).to eq(true)
      end
    end
```

it prints the following message.

```
 User user1 is expected to exist
```

Is there any way to suppress the message or customize it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspec supports [reporters](https://docs.chef.io/inspec/reporters/) to customize your output.
It's not entirely clear to me what you want changed from the output, but if you want something more terse, the `progress` or `progress-bar` reporters seem to be what you might be after.

```
inspec exec example_profile --reporter progress
```

looks like it will give you the classic progression of dots.

If you want to customize the output of the line,
The User class is defined in inspec at
https://github.com/inspec/inspec/blob/main/lib/inspec/resources/users.rb#L314

It just has a simple `to_s` method.

You could override that method in your setup. For example,

```
module Inspec::Resources
  class User
    def to_s
      "User (redacted)"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, I would like username not to appear in the output

Comment: I only get code formatting in the answer, so I'll answer there.